# Protecting HTML5 video

Tags: security, videos, html5

I shall explain my situation as best I can so you can see where i'm coming from. I'm working on a wordpress site for a sports team, there are loads of teams. We want to put coaching sessions on our site. This is so that all the coaches can see how the sessions should be done as many are parent coaches.

The problem is that there are a lot of coaches, in a very tight knit community, often families have kids in rival teams for other districts, so what we want to do is protect our material from either; just being downloaded by our coaches and shared with opposition coaches, or people who shouldn't have access to it in the first place, or people acquiring links to the videos and just accessing the videos themselves and possibly distributing them. There is a lot of movement with players and coaches between local teams. We need to maintain that all the work we are doing stays solely within our club and not allow somebody to leave and takes hours worth of footage and training sessions to a rival club.

All the coaching sessions are in private pages, I did start using youtube unlisted videos to stream the videos in, but this is insecure as you can just get the link from the source code and distribute it.

I'm now using HTML5 secure video player plugin, my videos are in a folder outside my document root, but it appears I can just right click the video and download it when it's playing in Chrome. This is obviously a problem too.

I saw using a CDN may avoid this too, I have got a cloudflare account - I'm a little lost really with how to protect these videos. This is my first real venture with video.

Does anybody have any advice in how to protect local HTML5 videos.

Comment: "I'm a little lost really with how to protect these videos" the answer probably is that you can't, but you can make it more difficult for people to steal them by taking the measures you are taking.

Comment: I know at it's core it's very difficult with the DMR. If I could disable Chrome's ability to just download it like an image I'd be fairly happy.

Comment: Can you clarify your question so that it is in some way specific - or at least *relevant* - to **WordPress**?

Comment: Other than it being on a Wordpress platform using HTML5 secure video player plugin - No

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First:**

You will need a plugin that acts as an intermediary for your cloud storage. Cloud storage innately (if setup properly) will protect your files. I have used the CDN Vault plugin and it works great. It's a premium plugin that depends on Amazon S3 storage. It does some really great obfuscation and encryption so your files aren't easily stolen.

**Second:**

You should setup membership functionality to restrict your content to members only if you're worried about stolen content. There are quite a few great membership plugins that allow you offer paid/free content to different levels all at once or slow-drip.

**Use Case**

CDN Vault worked great for a video tutorial subscription service I setup on WordPress for a client. They never had an issue with stolen content. We used the Wishlist membership plugin as well for restricting content to membership levels.

**Resources**

Check out the following sites to get you started. You will need to choose what feels best for  your use case.

- http://www.cdnvault.com/
- http://s3flowshield.com/
- http://member.wishlistproducts.com/
- http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/membership

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks Brian, I appreciate the response, I shall look into this in more detail, the problem is a difficult one, because what essentially we're doing is trying to make sure that members don't just distribute these videos to friends or family. I shall let you know how I got on.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problems as yourself.. I've exhausted many options at the minute .. I've gone down the route of videopress (but this had pitfalls for iOS devices), google drive but there is a high cost per user and you cannot just limit it to a domain.. (but you can limit it to users on a domain.) Rackspace cloud hosting.. but again they cannot limit it to a domain..

The only thing that has worked for me so far is vimeo/pro.. It is a tad expensive at €160 for 50gb but it does what I need..

How did you get on with cdnvault and s3flowshield?

Paul

Answer (score -2):

In Wordpress there are php script that can be include on wordpress index.php

What it does it will automatically protect your video.

This Script call Defa Protector.You can Google it.
Here is some video :
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TlzNT9vJF58

Comment: It would be great if you can include the script in your answer. As it currently stands, this is more of a comment than an answer as the answer revolves around an external link. If that link ever gets removed, your answer will be useless to future users. Please [edit] your answer and include all relevant info to make your answer complete