# Accessing a file saved outside webroot in a wordpress post

Tags: urls, filesystem

I have some files saved outside the `webroot` and need to allow posts in WordPress to be able to access the files.

Following is the location of one of the files:

```
/home1/Mathone/TESTS/Test1/index1.html
```

I created a `Download.php` file with the following code:

```
<?php
$path = '/home1/Mathone/TESTS/'. $_GET['filename'];
$mm_type="application/octet-stream"; 
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($path)) );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
readfile($path); // outputs the content of the file
exit();
?>
```

Next, I created a post in wordpress with the following link:

```
<a href="download.php?filename=Test1/index1.html">download</a>
```

I am getting an error

> This is somewhat embarrassing, isn’t it?
>   It seems we can’t find what you’re looking for. Perhaps searching can help.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I just saw this thread and I was wondering if this is an option for me. Instead of saving my html(and related data folder) outside of  <webroot>, I could save it on Amazon S3 storage and then use a plugin like CDNVault. Any thoughts on whether this would be a better option for me?       [link]http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42454/protecting-html5-video

Answer (score -2):

Try Absolute url not relative

Example:

> download.php?filename=http://www.yoursite.com/Test1/index1.html

Comment: Never hardcode URL's in a theme or plugin. It is just bad practice

Comment: You should post that as an [edit] to your answer. Code in comments are useless as they are unreadable and overlooked by future users